# How to modify a json object using json11 library?

Tags: c++, json, object

I have a already [json11](https://github.com/dropbox/json11) object build:

```
Json my_json = Json::object {
        { "key1", "value1" },
        { "key2", false },
        { "key3", Json::array { 1, 2, 3 } },
    };
```

And I want to add a new value to key3 array like this:

```
my_json["keys3"].push_back(4);
```

How I can achieve that? I can't see anything to  modify objects (all operator to access values are const!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems you cannot modify directly an instance of `Json`.
It's an opaque wrapper around a `JsonValue` that is inaccessible.

Anyway, note that a `Json::object` is a `std::map<std::string, Json>`. You can create a copy of your original `Json::object` as it follows:

```
Json::object json_obj = my_json.object_items();
```

Then the key `keys3` contains a `Json::array`, that is nothing more than a `std::vector<Json>`.
You can modify it as it follows:

```
json_obj["keys3"].push_back(4);
```

Finally you must create a new `Json` from your `Json::object` and that's all:

```
Json another_json = json_obj;
```

Quite expensive an operation.
I suspect the right way is to create your objects step by step and at the very end of your process create an instance of a `Json`.

Comment: Thanks @skypjack for your answer. I find some issue on github related to json11 project that explain that (I will put in a answer)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using json11 you can do it like this:

```
Json json = Json::object
{
  { 
     "num_neurons_in_each_layer", Json::array{ 1000, 1000, 10, 10 } 
  },
  { 
     "non_editable_data", 
      Json::object
      {
        {"train_error", -1.0 },
        {"validation_error", -1.0 }
      }
  }
};

Json* p_error = const_cast<Json*>(&json["non_editable_data"]. 
                object_items().find("validation_error")->second);

*p_error = Json(2.0); //"validation_error" has been modified to 2.0

p_error = nullptr;
delete p_error;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found next issues on github about this question:

- [https://github.com/dropbox/json11/issues/20]: more o less the same that skypjack explain

> The Json type is immutable, but the Json::object type is just a
>   std::map, so your code would work if the first line created a
>   Json::object instead. You can use that map to build whatever data you
>   want, then wrap it in as Json(data) when you're done modifying it. You
>   can also extract the map from a Json using object_items(), copy it,
>   mutate it, and use it to create a new Json, similar to a builder
>   pattern.

- [https://github.com/dropbox/json11/issues/75]: This one is very interesting because explain why it's not possible to modify a json

> The Json type is intended to be an immutable value type, which has a
>   number of advantages including thread safety and the ability to share
>   data across copies. If you want a mutable array you can use a
>   Json::array (which is just a typedef for a vector) and mutate it
>   freely before putting it into a Json object.